# each array and split per symbol

Tags: jquery, arrays, split, each

web guru.

I'm posting something to ajax. e.g data: array. 
Output 3-0 4-1, etc.

3 means a id="3"
0 or 1 means  $('answer_color_0') or $('answer_color_1')

How to coreectly loop to put in  $("a#"+oputput[0]).addClass("answer_"+output[1]);

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getResults").click(function(event) {
         var summary = [];
         $('#question a.active').each(function () { //clicked on the link
             summary.push($(this).attr('id')); //check a id="1"
          });
         $.post('post.php', {'data': summary}).done(function(msg, statusText) {
             var array = msg;
             for (var i in array){ 
                 var parts = array.split(" "); 
                 var ats1 = parts[0]; 
                 console.log(ats1); // output: 3-1<br/>4-0<br/> etc. 
              }
         });
    });
});
```

so how to put these numbers to positions? 
$("a#3).addClass("answer_1);

Comment: can you further elaborate? where you want to put $("a#"+oputput[0]).addClass("answer_"+output[1]) and what does this mean   "so how to put these numbers to positions? $("a#3).addClass("answer_1)".

Comment: output e.g: 3-1 4-0 means 3 is answer id ( $("a#3") <a id="3"> and 1 true, 0 - false. addClass(answer_1)  is red background or addClass(answer_0) is green background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can loop on each value like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getResults").click(function(event) {
        var summary = [];
        $('#question a.active').each(function () { //clicked on the link
            summary.push($(this).attr('id')); //check a id="1"
        });
        $.post('post.php', {'data': summary}).done(function(msg, statusText) {
            var array = msg;
            // Like this
            array.map(function(val){
                 var parts = val.split(" "); 
                 $('#'+parts[0]).addClass("answer_"+parts[1]);
                 console.log(ats1); // output: 3-1<br/>4-0<br/> etc. 
            });
            // Or this
            for (var i=0;i<array.length; i++){ 
                var parts = array[i].split(" "); 
                $('#'+parts[0]).addClass("answer_"+parts[1]);
                console.log(ats1); // output: 3-1<br/>4-0<br/> etc. 
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: it doesnt seems to work correctly. After loop it outputs  multiple values. because answers could be two or three, 3-0 40 5-1, etc. not one answer.

Comment: what will ats1 do? console.log(ats1) is loging each time loop is running.

Comment: outputs 3-1 or other values. so I need to put these to $('#3').addClass('answer_1"). I need to highlight wrong or good  answers. thats the point.

Comment: output:  

3
-
1 in  separated lines

Comment: I have mentioned two ways of looping. Which method you are using? You just need to use one.

Comment: using for(). but it not work as I need. Look. on website  I'm posting some answers. answers id is 2 3 4. checking in database. from database getting answer type 0 or 1. means true or false. so its 2-1 3-0,, etc. so I need to highlight these answers  2 3 4 to addClass('answer_1') or answer_0.

Comment: Fine. and ats1 is an array or no. Like [3, 1] where 3 is answer id and 1 is correct or wrong? or just a number?

Comment: Check now the updated answer. It seems to mee that value from db is a string like '3 1' which you are already spliting on the basis of ' '.